# If the word ends with an s, only cat apostrophe(') at the end of the word

Tags: r

Suppose the following fruity example:

```
canada <- c(48, 100, 56)
korea <- c(87, 79, 80)
laos <- c(20, 30, 10)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, laos)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")

> fruit
       apple orange banana
canada    48    100     56
korea     87     79     80
laos      20     30     10
```

I wanted to add a possessive structure, so I did the following:

```
price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- names(which(myrow == max(myrow)))

  cat(paste0(nation, "'s ", name.min, "s typically cost ",  score.min, " cents per unit (USD).")
      )

}
```

Which, generates the following sentence:

```
> price("laos")
Laos's bananas typically cost 10 cents per unit (USD).
```

I want to follow the AP News style and leave off the **s** at the apostrophe's end and only use the apostrophe (**'**) for words that end with an **s**. As always, thank you.

Comment: Change you `cat` statement to `cat(paste0(nation, ifelse(grepl("s$", nation), "' ", "'s "), 
 name.min, "s typically cost ",  score.min, " cents per unit (USD).")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to handle possessives, then call it in `price`:

```
possessive <- function(x) {
  ifelse(
    endsWith(x, "s"),
    paste0(x, "'"),
    paste0(x, "'s")
  )
}

price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- names(which(myrow == max(myrow)))

  cat(paste0(possessive(nation), " ", name.min, "s typically cost ",  score.min, " cents per unit (USD).")
  )

}
```

Comment: This works remarkably well. It is most appropriate for me to use because I can call it in `price` function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookbehind with `gsub`. The following only removes `s` if it is followed by `s'`:

```
price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- names(which(myrow == max(myrow)))

  string = paste0(nation, "'s ", name.min, "s typically cost ",  score.min, " cents per unit (USD).")

  string = gsub("(?<=s')s", "", string, perl = TRUE)

  cat(string)

}

price("laos")
# Laos' bananas typically cost 10 cents per unit (USD).
```